# Как выполнить редирект который приходит со стороннего апи?

Tags: node.js, express, cors

С сайта "http://localhost" отправляется POST запрос на "http://localhost:3000/api/test", который возвращает редирект (302) на другой сайт, но в консоль браузера вылетает:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://google.com/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/api/test') from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Запрос, который возвращает 302 обрабатывается Node.js (express), CORS включил.
Хочу понять почему это не работает, и какие есть обходные решения?

Пример POST запроса:

```js
function test() {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/test", true);
      xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В классическом подходе к реализации api для web есть довольно мало весомых причин генерировать 302 в ответ на запрос с клиента. Например, есть определённый смысл, если ресурс действительно был перемещён и мы информируем клиента об этом.

Вы пишете `api` - так и пишите его! Запрос на http://localhost:3000/api/test должен вернуть

```
{
  "redirect_url": "https://google.com/"
}
```

и клиентская часть вашего приложения должна обработать этот ответ подгрузив новую страницу.